# Can a chip be damaged if it goes above operating temperature while running?

Tags: temperature, semiconductors, component-failure

An image sensor I'm using has the following temperature spec:

**Absolute Maximums:**

- Ambient storage Temperature Max: 125°C

**Recommended Operating Conditions:**

- Stable image temperature Max: 50ºC
- Operating temperature Max: 70°C

---

The chip is running inside a heated mould, where the temperature goes above the chip's maximum recommended operating temperature, to about 105ºC, (but still well below 125ºC). As the temperature rises above 50ºC, the image begins to get noisy, and it eventually stops transmitting an image. After 1 hour, the mould is allowed to cool down, and the image sensor is removed back to a room-temperature environment.

Occasionally we see some chips fail permanently, where they output a corrupt image, full of noise and lines.

**Question:**

Could the chip be damaged by going above its operating temperature *while powered*. I.e. if we powered down the chip before it went over temperature, might that reduce the number of failures we're seeing? (Note that, since it's inside a heated mould, it would still reach 105ºC).

**Added:** Does anyone know of an instance where any kind of chip failed because it was powered while being at a temperature between max operating and max storage?

Comment: It should improve - otherwise they probably wouldn't split the specification like that, but you should also consider how fast the cooling happens, rapid temperature changes (pulling it out into a cold environment vs letting it slowly cool with the mould for example) could also impact the failure rate. I don't know the failure modes for image sensors, so I'm not entirely sure if there is something specific here.

Comment: The max. storage temp tells you the maximum. This is also (usually) the maximum operating temperature of the die. So I think the specs are telling you that under normal operation they (or you) may increase the die temperature by 55 C over ambient, so under no circumstances exceed 70 C. So yes, when at 105 C and if they add another 55 C for operation, that puts things at 160 C. Which is definitely exceeding specs. I'd guess that metal migration may be how permanent injury occurs over time. But perhaps a datasheet would help here. I'm just guessing.

Comment: The max (and min) storage temperatures are usually higher/lower that the operating temperature range, except maybe in the case of fully qualified Mil-Spec parts (-55 C to +125 C).

Comment: Electrical and chemical properties in many materials are strongly temperature dependant.  A current that is harmless at ambient temperatures in an IC may result in substantial relocation of ions, leakage of current into unintended paths or other damage at 150C for example.  So yes, it is certainly possible that you can damage a part by powering it up before it cools down.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for having separate storage and operating temperatures is because they are indeed different things.

An unpowered part at elevated temperatures is subject to very different stresses to a powered part.  In particular, loss of control from current regulating elements inside an unpowered part is not an issue, whilst for a powered device this could cause permanent damage.

The same is true when you consider the ability of many parts to withstand reflow soldering, but not to be powered when this happens (as they may undergo thermal runaway or other damage).

In your case, I would incorporate a temperature sensor into the assembly, and have the power removed from sensor when the temperature goes above the max operating temperature.  From what you say  there is no image there anyway at elevated temperature, so no need for it to be powered on.

Answer (score 2):

We could make a better assessment if you had provided a link to the data sheet.  Nevertheless...

> Recommended Operating Conditions:
>
> ```
> Stable image temperature Max: 50ºC
> Operating temperature Max: 70°C
> ```

This tells you that the sensor will operate properly (stable image) up to 50°C.  It also tells you that the sensor will operate somewhat up to 70°C.

Lacking a parameter called Absolute Max Operating Temperature (or something similar), above which chip operation is not specified and above which damage could occur, I can only conclude that damage MAY occur if the temperature, while operating, exceeds 70°C.

Note the operating temp range is only loosely coupled to storage temperature range.  Most Si devices, since they are all based on the same basic materials, have similar storage temperature ranges.  Also storage temperature (and other storage parameters like humidity and shock) may be more related to the type of package used than the Si die.

**Edit 1: You further said that:**

> The chip is running inside a heated mould, where the temperature goes above the chip's maximum recommended operating temperature, to about 105ºC

So then there you have it.  You are using the chip outside of it's specified operating temperature range.  All bets about performance are off.

> if we powered down the chip before it went over temperature, might that reduce the number of failures we're seeing?

Yes, although if the chip is not powered, how would you know if it's failed or not?  Exposing an un-powered chip to 125°C should not, in most cases cause it to fail when powered back up under normal operating conditions, particularly T<70°C.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed the datasheet might be useful, but A) I think this is a more useful question to the community if the answers apply generally to chips, and B) I have the datasheet under NDA, so I cannot share it.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet there are very different failure modes for different kind of chips, some are probably true for all, but some are certainly very specific (for example flash cells have some very specific failure modes), so there is a general answer, which are given here, but there might be more specific ones, based on the chip - if the datasheet is under NDA, then you could/should also inquire the manufacturer. Sometimes they give you are more insightful answer than just "If you use it outside of the spec anything can happen".